# JSP giving error: Requested resource not found

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Just need a little help.

I tried to make a small test project but I'm stuck at this error. Having all my JAR files and JSPs well placed:

`The requested resource (/LibrayManagement/list_of_books_available.jsp) is not available`

Following is the jsp code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Listofbooksaction" method="post">

<h3>List of books available</h3>

<c:forEach var = "list" items = "${requestScope.BooksList}">

<c:out value = "${list[0]}">

</c:out>

</c:forEach>

<input type= "submit" value = "get list">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is Action class code :

```
import java.sql.* ;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**

public class Listofbooksaction extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    String url = "list_of_books_available.jsp";
    public Listofbooksaction() {
        super();

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ConnectionsList c = new ConnectionsList() ;


        try {
            Statement St = c.createconnection();
            ResultSet Rs = St.executeQuery("Select * from books_list") ;
            System.out.println(Rs);

            ArrayList<String> Books_List = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(Rs.next())
            {
                Books_List.add(Rs.getString(1));
            }

            request.setAttribute("BooksList", Books_List);

            response.sendRedirect(url);

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

}
```

Error Stacktrace:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:4‌​35) Listofbooksaction.doPost(Listofbooksaction.java:62) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)`

Comment: What does `url` contain?

Comment: Where is the JSP located in the webapp? What's the point to store attributes in the request if you redirect to a JSP right after? You probably want a forward, and not a redirect.

Comment: the problem is that the jsp page doesn't exist in the place where web contents are. You need to manually add the page so the servlet is able to reference it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for Reply . I copied all relevant files to web-app now its working but i am having another error saying "Illegal State Exception" i tried adding return statement but got error again.

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: its as follows : java.lang.IllegalStateException
 org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
 Listofbooksaction.doPost(Listofbooksaction.java:62)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: How do you access the JSP which you have placed in the code ?